# Is κεχαριτωμένος synonymous with δεδικαιωμένος?

Tags: greek, word-study, latin-vulgate, sirach

Jerome translated "ἀνδρὶ κεχαριτωμένῳ" (a man who has been graced) as "homine iustificato" (justified man).  **Is κεχαριτωμένος synonymous with δεδικαιωμένος?**

> οὐκ ἰδοὺ λόγος ὑπὲρ δόμα ἀγαθόν; καὶ ἀμφότερα παρὰ **ἀνδρὶ
>   κεχαριτωμένῳ**.
>   Sirach 18:17 (Septuagint)
>
> Look! Does not a word exceed a good gift? And both are with **a man who has been favored.**
>   Sirach 18:17 (NETS)
>
> nonne ecce verbum super datum bonum et utraque cum **homine
>   iustificato**
>   Sirach 18:17 (Latin Vulgate)
>
> Lo, is not a word better than a gift? but both are with a **justified
>   man**
>   Sirach 18:17 (Douay-Rheims 1899 American Edition)

Comment: Is there a way you could change the title - to be a little more "search friendly"?  Maybe something like, "In Sirach 18, are 'Favored' and 'Justified' synonymous?"  ... I honestly don't know a better way to title Greek questions, like this.

Answer (score 1):

Both are perfect passive participles of their verbs.  κεχαριτωμένος is a participle of the verb χαριτόω; δεδικαιωμένος is a participle of the verb δικαιόω.

The verse you cite in Sirach is actually the only occurrence of χαριτόω in the Septuagint and the word occurs only twice in the New Testament (including once by Paul, in Ephesians).  It is closely related, however, to the word χάρις, meaning "grace" or "kindness"; and to the verb χαιρω, which means "to be glad" or "rejoice".

δικαιόω is related to δίκαιος, which the King James translates as "just", "righteous", and occassionally "right" or "meet".  Most Lexicons define δικαιόω as "to justify" or "declare righteous".  The late Orthodox Christian commentator Dmitry Royster discusses these two terms:

> The terms "just" (Greek *dikaos*) and "justify" (*dikaioō*) are
>   obviously related terms, the first usually being translated as
>   "righteous" and sometimes as "just",  and the second as "justified"; 
>   a third related word *dikaiosynē* [δικαιοσύνη] is most often
>   translated as "righteousness".  There exists a problem among
>   interpreters, especially our contemporaries, concerning the
>   relationship among these three:  most reject the possibility of
>   translating the verb *dikaioō* as "to make righteous", using rather
>   "to justify", and doing so in a juridical sense, that is, of being
>   acquitted of guilt before God's tribunal.
>
> [*St. Paul's Epistle to the Romans: A Pastoral Commentary*](http://amzn.to/2mO40UU), p.58

Although the Latin easily lends it self to the anglicization "justify", the Latin *iustifico* can also mean to "make right", but neither of these meanings seem to accord very well with the Greek meaning of κεχαριτωμένος.  Whether δικαιόω means to justify in the legal sense or to make righteous, the meaning of χαριτόω seems to be completely distinct.  Perhaps Jerome or some later translator was imputing some relationship between grace and "justification" in choosing the Latin word they did.

Answer (score 0):

κεχαριτωμένος ‘having been graced’ is a participle (verbal adjective). δικαίωσις ‘justification’ is an abstract noun. Synonyms ought at least to be the same part of speech.

PS. The question changed after I wrote this.